Airflow SSH Operator bash commands are failing Intermittently
We are currently running multiple bash commands through Airflow 2.7.3 version under Google Cloud Composer.
from airflow.providers.ssh.operators.ssh import SSHOperator

task_exec = SSHOperator(
    task_id='additonal_info',
    command="ksh -x execute.ksh paramter1",
    ssh_conn_id="SSH_CONNECTION",
    conn_timeout=432000,       
)

Sometimes command runs for 1 hour , sometime  to 8 hours and sometimes with in  30-40 minutes commands fails with returning no error at the bottom of Airflow task but it will be failed state in Airflow.
Could any one pls suggest what can be done to fix this issue

There are too many possibilities for this to be answered well. Is the connection to the remote server being established when there is this failure? Does execute.ksh do any sort of logging that you can see what's happening for runs that go longer than anticipated? Is there anything in the log for the airflow run that hints at what's going on?

@JNevill , I have even added manual logging in the script for any every 10 seconds to capture the log whether the bash command is in progress or failed.
There is no error or anything in the airflow log and all of us sudden the task is going into failed state and last line of the log will be as per shell script logging with no error messagge or any other clue

Are you able to access the remote system directly and see if there is any logging on its side? It might be worth checking places like /var/log/auth.log on that remote system (assuming linux) to see if there is any smoking gun there. Then see what execute.ksh is up to and if it creates any logging that you could investigate while on that system.

@JNevill , Yes I can access the remote system and I dont see any specific error and I tried all the ways like script.ksh >> log.txt and other logging methods and nothing is returning . Although in the remote system the command is active and running perfectly it fails in Airflow without displaying any error message or end message in the task log

one thing you can check is if the shell script returns with exit 0 for all the cases .. if not airflow can mark it as failed task.

Can you attach logs for the task instance? My first guess would be an underlying infrastructure issue with the Cloud Composer cluster, based on your comment: "last line of the log will be as per shell script logging with no error message or any other clue"
